# Can't access my wp admin: captcha images invisible, gives me error message

Tags: admin, login, captcha

I have a captcha plugin, and to access my admin page I need to select the right captcha image. Since this morning on the login page the captcha part does not appear and when I enter my id and psswd it gives me an error message saying that I used the wrong image.
What shall I do ?

Thanks for your help, I'm a simple user, not a computer science savvy

Answer (score 2):

You can disable that plugin without accessing your Wordpress Dashboard.

You need to navigate to your Wordpress installation folder, then to `wp-content/plugins` and then look for the folder with it and rename it. This will disable the plugin and you should be able to login.

Afterwards, I suggest you to contact the plugin developers and describe the issue that you faced.

Comment: I can't have access to wordpress otherwise than through the dashboard. My blog is not hosted by wordpress.
In other words I have never navigated to my Wordpress installation folder and don't know how to do it, if it is possible in my case.

Comment: If you have a hosting place to host your site, then you log into your hosting account and use the File Manager there to find the plugins folder.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked out.
Sweet Captcha plugin is hacked, reason why it creates problems. I removed it definitely.